# Dynamically changing fragment contents in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have:

- A `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` on (or a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, doesn't really solve my problem).
- A fixed number of fragments. They all share the same layout, but have `TextView`s that need to be set differently;
- An `AsyncTask` that queries my database and retrieves content to be set into the TextViews.

So my code was:

```
public class StatsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 5;
    private Parameters[] sectionData;

    public StatsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.sectionData = new Parameters[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return StatsSectionFragment.getInstance(this.sectionData[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
    }

    public void setSectionData(int position, Parameters sectionData) {
        this.sectionData[position] = sectionData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

So I'm passing `sectionData[position]` to the `getInstance()` method of my generic sub-fragment. That data should differentiate each instance of the fragments loaded into the `ViewPager`.

At first I'll be passing an empty reference, but then in my async class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Parameters... sectionValues) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(sectionValues);
        mPagerAdapter.setSectionData(sectionId, sectionValues[0]);
    }
```

That should call the `setSectionData()` above, update `sectionData[position]` and generate a call to `notifiyDataSetChanged()`. I was hoping that doing so would make the adapter retrieve all its items again, thus calling `getItem()` again, and loading new fragments.

Sadly it does not. So right now:

- if fragments (i.e., `getItem()`) are created before my async task result are published, that item will stay empty (i.e.,visible fragment, but with empty text views since I never called `getInstance(non-null stuff)`.
  That happens for fragment 0 && fragment 1.
- if fragments are created after my async task has ended (fragment 2 to end, because `getItem()` is called only when you reach that fragment by swiping), then the first and only call to `getItem()` produces a `getInstance(non-null stuff)`, and that's ok.

How can I reload content into those already-there fragments, or force the adapter to call `getItem()` and update its views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}
```

This make your adapter call `getItem` again when you call  `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Works only with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but that's ok for me.